# VEML6075 UVA and UVB measuring ranges

Tags: arduino, range, sensors, measurement, datasheet

I use a VEML6075 sensor to read UVA, UVB, and UV index. The UV Index is automatically calculated by the chip, also sent by I2C to my MCU.
According to the next Datasheets:

[Vishay Datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/3/c/3/2/f/veml6075.pdf)

[Adafruit VEML6075](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-veml6075-uva-uvb-uv-index-sensor.pdf)

[Vishay  Application Note](http://www.patarnott.com/atms748/pdf/Class2018/designingveml6075_VishayUVaUVbsensors.pdf)

It can present the raw data for UVA and UVB. These values are presented in counts/μW/cm2 and it depends on the measured channels.
My problem is that I don't know about the measuring range for this raw data

```
uint16_t uva = my_veml6075.getUVA();
uint16_t uvb = my_veml6075.getUVB();
```

Have anybody the range for these two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no upper limit. At some point your sensor will be saturated.

As the datasheet states this sensor is for solar irradiation. You should not use focussing optics of course. So in the intended use case the sensor will probably not saturate.

It returns the UVA and UVB levels as a 16bit value.

The value is returned as `counts/µW/cm²`

To get the UV index from a irradiation value divide it by `25W/m²`

The highest UV index ever measured was 43.3

Typically the values range between 0 and 12. Thats a maximum of `300mW/m²`

Comment: Thank You for Your fast answer! I need a plausible realistic value for UVA and UVB that will be reached at maximal UV index, (for example at UV index 12). The problem is that I need this data for my application that I write. A gauge shows both UVA and UVB values, but I must set a maximal value for a gauge, and I have no information about these values at UV index 12 or higher. Have You an idea of what can be a realistic value for UVA and UVB by UV index of 12? Thank You!

Comment: I don't understand your question. you know the that 1 count is 1µW/cm² and you know that the typical range is 0-300mW/m²   what else do you need?  there are recommendations for UV exposure and what measures to take for each index. those measures won't change above 10

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RZkg.png)

For UVA 65536:0.93=70 469 uW/cm2

For UVB 65536:2.1= 31 207 uW/cm2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).